# Remove expect_any_instance_of RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a stub on a particular class method that is valid for most of my tests. I setup the mock in a before block to DRY my test up. I want to remove the stub for one test where it is not valid. How do I do this using RSpec?

Code

```
before :all do
 expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:callback)
end

it 'does a callback on this test' do
 Foo.new
end

it 'does it in this too!' do
 Foo.new.other
end

it 'doesnt do it in this one' do
 # how do i remove the stub???
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use different `context`'s so you can describe 1 behavior vs. another like so:

```
describe 'something' do
  context 'valid with callback' do
    before :each do
      expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:callback)
    end

    it 'does a callback on this test' do
      Foo.new
    end

    it 'does it in this too!' do
      Foo.new.other
    end
  end

  context 'invalid with callback' do
    it 'doesnt do it in this one' do
      # how do i remove the stub???
    end
  end
end
```

In the above code the `before :each` block is only local to the `valid with callback` context, so you can test that isolated behavior there.

Answer (score 0):

**update:** `expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:bar).and_call_original`

But, consider that it may be a smell if you are mocking every instance of a class. There may be cleaner alternatives for structuring your test.